# OpenOffice disable track changes via UNO (Java) interface

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org, change-tracking, uno, openoffice-writer

How can I disable track changes in OpenOffice Writer / LibreOffice Writer using the UNO Java API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry point seems to be [this](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/servicecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1text_1_1GenericTextDocument.html#a6649fa1a4963f78b9d70a85edef770e4).